# `changeset()` spec requires nullable type which is not logically nullable

Tags: types, elixir, dialyzer, typespec

I have the following code:

```
defmodule Foo do
  @moduledoc false

  use Ecto.Schema

  import Ecto.Changeset


  @type t :: %__MODULE__{
          id: integer(),
          foo: String.t(),
          baz_id: String.t(),
          bar: String.t() | nil
        }

  embedded_schema do
    field :foo, :string
    field :bar, :string
  end

  @spec changeset(t() | Ecto.Changeset.t(), map()) :: Ecto.Changeset.t()
  def changeset(bae \\ %__MODULE__{}, attrs) do
    bae
    |> cast(attrs, @fields)
    |> unique_constraint(:baz_id)
  end
end
```

`foo` and `baz_id` should not be `nil`, as per the `@type` definition.
However, `dialyzer` is complaining (with the given `@spec`) because the default value `%__MODULE__{}` will set them to `nil`.

If I replace the `@type` definition with:

```
...
  @type t :: %__MODULE__{
          id: integer() | nil,
          foo: String.t() | nil,
          baz_id: String.t() | nil,
          bar: String.t() | nil
        }
...
```

then `dialyzer` will not complain, but I am no longer capturing the idea that some of the fields are not nullable.

What would be an elegant way to make `changeset()` work the way it currently is, and avoid having `dialyzer` complaining for this specific use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you’re explicitly specifying the default argument that violates a dialyzer contract (the schema is a bare [struct underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66223352/changeset-spec-requires-nullable-type-which-is-not-logically-nullable) without default values,) that’s why dialyzer complains.

It is unclear, how you do suppose to handle an empty `%__MODULE__{}` once it’s not allowed, but answering the question stated, the workaround would be to accept `nil` argument as a default.

```rb
@spec changeset(
    nil | t() | Ecto.Changeset.t(), map()
  ) :: Ecto.Changeset.t()
def changeset(bae \\ nil, attrs) do
  bae
  |> Kernel.||(%__MODULE__{})
  |> cast(attrs, @fields)
  |> unique_constraint(:baz_id)
end
```